# Silverlight/ASP.NET - Pointing to Database Dynamically using ADO.NET/Domain Services

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, wcf, ado.net, sql-server-express

I am new to Silverlight and I am following the [Silverlight for Business Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/silverlight4trainingcourse_sl4lob_02_01_riaservices) tutorial. I've connected up a MDF file using an ADO.NET Entity Model and a Domain Service, as shown in the video and all of these work fine.

The complication comes from needing to point to a database dynamically.

In my application, users will log in. Once logged in, the program will tailor the experience based on the user. This means I need to point to a user specific database, from within the Silverlight application, after authentication.

I've figured out how to change the connection string of a model by changing the code behind, as shown in the code below. However, I'm not so sure I can make it work using that or how to make it work using that, since there isn't a direct connection between the Silverlight app and ASP.NET.

```
string fileName = string.Empty;
void OnContextCreated()
{
    this.Connection.ConnectionString = GenerateConnectionString(".\\SQLEXPRESS", "|DataDirectory|\\" + fileName + ".mdf");
}

public static string GenerateConnectionString(string dbServer, string fileName)
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

    // Set the properties for the data source.
    sqlBuilder.DataSource = dbServer;
    //sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = dbName;
    //sqlBuilder.UserID = "YOUR_USERNAME";
    //sqlBuilder.Password = "YOUR_PASSWORD";
    sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    sqlBuilder.AttachDBFilename = fileName;
    sqlBuilder.UserInstance = true;
    sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
    sqlBuilder.ApplicationName = "EntityFramework";

    // Build the SqlConnection connection string.
    string providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

    // Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
    EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

    //Set the provider name.
    entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";

    // Set the provider-specific connection string.
    entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerString;

    // Set the Metadata location.
    entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/Model.csdl|
                   res://*/Model.ssdl|
                   res://*/Model.msl";

    return entityBuilder.ToString();
}
```

If at all possible, I would like to stick to the methods shown in the video, using the Domain Services and the ADO.NET Entity Models because I gain access to the RIA Services functionality allowing me to drag and drop tables, push changes, etc. with great ease.

How can I point to a database at runtime while still using the methods shown in the video?

**Edit**

All the SQL databases that I will be pointing to have an identical layout. That is, they have the same tables and fields. User specific data is populated into these fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this successfully you need to have a separate data layer.

If you're following MVVM then there should be no data access code in the view code behind files anyway.

Eitherway I suggest that you add a new library project to your solution that will implement your data layer code. This library will make public only those methods required to get your data and those should be defined in a public interface type. All of your business logic will refer to this interface or a class that implements it. The rest of your datalayer code should be declared as internal if they need to be public witin the project.

Then you can implement a property whereby you pass the data layer the connection string for the database.

If you need to use different types of database e.g. SQL or Oracle, on the fly then you can use a factory pattern to instantiate a class that implements the interface, but is specific to that database type.

When implemented in this manner your business logic doesn't need to change in any way when access different databases.

MVVM pattern tends to be the default for Silverlight/WPF applications, but you'll tend to find that most teaching examples use the default pattern, whereby business logic resides within the code behind files. This is okay until you start to try and implement big changes to either your data access code or business logic when you'll find yourself changing a lot more code than you need to.

***edit***

Here's some links detailing MVVM and Silverlight.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd458800.aspx

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/the-mvvm-pattern/using-the-mvvm-pattern-in-silverlight-applications

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/MVVMSilverlight.aspx

Here's some links detailing Repository Pattern for data layer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx

http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33695/0/page/5

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/linqrepository.aspx

Comment: Hello ChrisBD. Thanks for the reply.

As I mentioned, I am new to Silverlight and Web Programming in general. I am much more fluent in desktop applications, such as console applications and XNA. A lot of the stuff you said, I did not understand.

Could you please elaborate how I can go about implementing the MVVM pattern? If you could link me to a sample that achieves my goals or point me towards a resource that I could learn from, that would be great. 

Thanks!

Comment: Added some links for you which may be of help.